# Call a normal JS function of other file after data from $http is loaded and is binded to the views

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to call a regular `JavaScript` function after my webservice call has completed and all the data is binded to the respective views.

This `JS` function is in another file so I cannot access it in my `Controller` using `$broadcast` etc.

My webservice call gets data and fills it in an accordion, but the problem is the webservice is sometimes taking too long to return data; due to which the normal `JS` function is called prior to the completion of webservice call, the purpose of the normal `JS` function here is to provide expand functionality to the accordion `li's` which are filled from the webservice call, due to the above reason, the expand functionality is not binded to the `li` elements as they are generated after successful data return.

I do not want to use $delay or anything of that sort as I cannot say for sure how long it will take for the data to return.

What is the way to get around this, where and how can I call my normal `JS` function? 
Can I defer the call of `function` in the directive itself or somewhere in the `HTML` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your 'normal JS function' using AngularJS 'service' / 'factory' / 'provider', you can then access it from anywhere using dependency injection of AngularJS.